# Missing wrapAll() callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I've seen there are callbacks for [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) as well for [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) but I've noticed there are no callback function for [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Does it mean the operation takes place in a synchronously way instead of asynchronously?

Would it be correct if I do something like this?

```
$('.test').wrapAll('<div id="demo" />');
$('#demo').css('height', '100px');   //using the previous appended selector
```

It seems to work, but I'm not pretty sure if it would under any occasion.

Comment: I don't  even think `wrap()` nor `wrapInner()` work in an asynchronous manner. Also, your example is useless as there can only be one element with the ID `demo`, but I don't think it's your actual code. A callback in those two methods is simply used to define a wrapping per element within the matched set of elements, not as a callback for an asynchronous request.

Comment: All of them are synchronous. Check what the function argument is used for, it is not an asynchronous callback.

Comment: @Derija93 is not my actual code, but the example makes sense. It wraps all the elements with the class `test` with only one `div` with the unique id `demo`.

Comment: @Bergi does it mean, I can work the appended elements as far as I use them under this line inside the same function?

Comment: @Alvaro Sorry, you're right. I misinterpreted the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will work because none of the wrap functions are asynchronous. The functions you pass are merely if you want to do something more complex than wrapping the elements with a single dom object. The following example creates divs using the element's text as a class, instead of just wrapping a div around the text:

```
$( ".inner" ).wrapInner(function() {
  return "<div class='" + this.nodeValue + "'></div>";
});
```

Check out the [docs for wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) for more info and examples :)

Comment: does it mean, I can work the appended elements as far as I use them under this line inside the same function? I'm trying to create the structure to with with on a plugin, and I wonder if wrapping things at the start will allow me to deal with the final structure without problems.

Comment: Since `.wrap`, `.wrapInner`, and `wrapAll` are all synchronous functions, when you call `$('.test').wrapAll('<div id="demo" />');`, nothing else can happen until your wrapAll command has completely executed. So the answer is yes, you can work the appended elements as long as you use them under this line inside the same function :)